# search feature not work for certain words

Tags: php, mysql

The problem I faced is when search word "anti" it will display the product but when search based words "anti wrinkle" mentioned no search result. Please refer below for the code and advice what do I missed.

```
$search_output = '';

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchsql = $_POST['search'];
    $searchsql = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!@-]#i', '', $searchsql);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT tb_spa_prd.*, tb_spa_prd_cat.spa_prd_cat FROM tb_spa_prd AS tb_spa_prd INNER JOIN tb_spa_prd_cat ON tb_spa_prd.spa_prd_cat_id = tb_spa_prd_cat.spa_prd_cat_id WHERE spa_prd_cat LIKE '%$searchsql%' or spa_prd_code LIKE '%$searchsql%' or spa_prd_name LIKE '%$searchsql%'")  or die ("Could no search!");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
        $search_output .= '<tr>
                            <td colspan="9" style="text-align: center">There was no search results!</td>
                            </tr>';
    } else {
        $row_no = 1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
            $spa_prd_id = $row["spa_prd_id"];
            $spa_prd_cat = $row["spa_prd_cat"];
            $spa_prd_code = $row["spa_prd_code"];
            $spa_prd_name = $row["spa_prd_name"];
            $spa_prd_vlm = $row["spa_prd_vlm"];
            $spa_prd_qty = $row["spa_prd_qty"];
            $spa_prd_crt_date = $row["spa_prd_crt_date"];
            $spa_prd_crt_usr = $row["spa_prd_crt_usr"];
            $search_output .= '<tr>
                                    <td>'.$row_no++.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$spa_prd_cat.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$spa_prd_code.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$spa_prd_name.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$spa_prd_vlm.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$spa_prd_qty.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$spa_prd_crt_date.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$spa_prd_crt_usr.'</td>
                            <td><a href=\'edit_spa_prd.php?spa_prd_id='.$spa_prd_id.'\'>Edit</a> | <a href=\'delete_spa_prd.php?spa_prd_id='.$spa_prd_id.'\'>Delete</a></td>
                                </tr>';
        } // close while loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting all your code, it's better to include only the needed part. You shall print the query and run it in your phpmyadmin to see the result or debug yourself

Comment: I would recommend you to use fulltext index for the columns you use in search.

Comment: @Quinn If you want `"anti wrinkle"` to fire you will need to include a separate `LIKE` predicate for _each_ term, q.v. my response below.

Answer (score 0):

You can try explicitly including a `LIKE` predicate for *each* search term like this:

```
$searchsql = $_POST['search'];
$terms = explode(" ", $searchsql);
$likecols = array("spa_prd_cat", "spa_prd_code, "spa_prd_name");
$likesql = "";
foreach ($likecols as $likecol) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($terms); ++$i) {
        if ($likecol == "spa_prd_cat" && $i == 0) {
            $likesql = "spa_prd_cat LIKE $terms[0]";
        }
        else {
            $likesql .= " OR $likecol LIKE $terms[$i]";
        }
    }
}

$querystr = "SELECT tb_spa_prd.*, tb_spa_prd_cat.spa_prd_cat FROM tb_spa_prd AS tb_spa_prd INNER JOIN tb_spa_prd_cat ON tb_spa_prd.spa_prd_cat_id = tb_spa_prd_cat.spa_prd_cat_id WHERE ";
$querystr .= $likesql;
$query = mysql_query($querystr) or die ("Could no search!");
```

Comment: sorry. I am quite newbie to this. I tried your provided code but mentioned could not search. As well I really not sure '$i' is referring to. Please advice.

Comment: If you want to search for `"anti wrinkle"` you can use `LIKE 'anti' OR LIKE 'wrinkle'`.  My code attempts to do this.